# Is it possible in Java to call a protected method from a different non-child class without using reflection?

Tags: java, overloading

I have this code snippet:

```java
abstract class Foo {
    protected abstract void method(String o);

    public void method(Object o) {
        System.out.println("method(Object)");
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    protected void method(String key) {
        System.out.println("method(String)");
    }
}

public class OverloadingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.method("hello");
        bar.method(null);
    }
}
```

which, to my surprise prints

```
method(String)
method(String)
```

on `stdout`, I would like to understand how it is possible since the method that accepts a String argument (which is the one that is called) is a protected method and it shouldn't be possible to call it from a class that is not does not extends `Foo`, the public method that accepts an `Object` should be called instead, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: `protected` means package-private and subclasses only.  The classes you have here all live in the same package.

Comment: Also when overriding, it is not possible to reduce the visibility.

Comment: @user2478398 ah, yeah.. you are absolutely right!

Comment: @Arnaud I know and I'm not doing that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, any code in the same package as `Bar` can access its protected methods.

If you were to move `OverloadingTest` to a new package -- i.e. move it to a file in a different folder in your source tree -- then only the `Foo#method(Object)` signature would be visible.

Protected visibility is a slightly more relaxed version of package-private AKA default visibility. The only difference between the two is that protected visibility allows a subclass to access the member even if it is in a different package.

To quote the [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) on the matter:

> The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.